How to Automatically Handle Closed Train Versions in Fastlane for iOS Builds?
I'm automating the build and release process for my iOS application using Fastlane and have run into a problem with version management that stops my process cold. I'm hoping to find a way to resolve this programmatically without manual intervention.
Here are the methods I'm using to manage the build number and version name:
Method to Get Build Number:
def bump_build_number()
  latest_build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(initial_build_number: 0)
  return (latest_build_number + 1)
end

Method to Get Version Name:
def get_version_name()
  version_name = lane_context[SharedValues::LATEST_TESTFLIGHT_VERSION]
  
  if version_name.empty?
    puts "*** Version name is empty, adding version 1.0.0 ***"
    version_name = "1.0.0"
  end
  
  return version_name
end

Using the Variables:
build_number = bump_build_number()
version_name = get_version_name()
sh("flutter", "build", "ipa", "--release", "--build-number=#{build_number}", "--build-name=#{version_name}", "--flavor=production")

Everything seems to work fine up to this point. However, when I run fastlane ios release_beta, the App Store returns the following error and halts the process:
ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] Asset validation failed (90186) Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.1.16' is closed for new build submissions (ID: xxxxx)

Issue:
The error message indicates that the version '1.1.16' is closed for new build submissions. I need to handle this error programmatically to ensure the build and version numbers are correctly managed and the process runs smoothly without any manual actions.
Question:
How can I automatically handle this error and update the version number appropriately to prevent the process from stopping?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
